# Use JQuery to Replace type of tag with same ID

Tags: jquery

I wish to use JQuery to replace (backward and forward)

```
<a id="my_id">abc</a>
```

to

```
<span id="my_id">abc</span>
```

May I know how I can do so in JQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#my_id").each(function(){
     $(this).replaceWith("<a id=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</a>");
});
```

Comment: actually he wants to change it to a span FROM a anchor but that's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
$('#my_id').replaceWith('<span id="my_id">abc</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This has the benefit of transfering all attributes from the anchor to the span (not just the id).

```
var cacheAttr = $('#my_id').attr();
var newSpan = $('<span></span>').attr(cacheAttr);
$('#my_id').replaceWith(newSpan);
```